# PHPExcel - How to simplify setting a single cell with 2 font sizes

Tags: phpexcel, richtext

I have a spreadsheet I'm creating with PHPExcel ... and I'm trying to create a single cell that has 14pt text followed by 10pt font (all within the same cell).

I've been able to create a test routine that works ... but it seems a lot more verbose that I think it should be.

Can someone show me how I can simplify setting the font for each of these two segments of text.

Here is the code I created for testing ...

```
<?php
require_once './Classes/PHPExcel.php';
require_once './Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

$phpColor = new PHPExcel_Style_Color();
$phpColor->setRGB("0070C0");

$objRichText = new PHPExcel_RichText();
$run1 = $objRichText->createTextRun('Main Part of the Title, ');
$run1->getFont()->setBold(true);
$run1->getFont()->setName("Calibri");
$run1->getFont()->setSize("14");
$run1->getFont()->setColor($phpColor);

$run2 = $objRichText->createTextRun(' and some extra');
$run2->getFont()->setBold(true);
$run2->getFont()->setName("Calibri");
$run2->getFont()->setSize("10");
$run2->getFont()->setColor($phpColor);

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue("A1", $objRichText);
header ( 'Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet' );
header ( 'Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="sq_test.xlsx"' );
header ( 'Cache-Control: max-age=0' );
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter ( $objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007' );
$objWriter->save ( 'php://output' );
?>
```

Specifically I tried using the following instead of all the $run2->getFont() lines ...

```
$run2->getFont()->applyFromArray(array("font" => array( "bold" => true, "size" => 10, "name" => "Calibri", "color" => $phpColor)));
```

And it didn't generate an error ... but didn't adjust the font from it's default settings ... but this is the kind of simplification that I would really like if it's possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the final version, with only 2 lines for each portion of the text, (much thanks to @Mark_Baker) is:

```
<?php
require_once './Classes/PHPExcel.php';
require_once './Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

$phpColor = new PHPExcel_Style_Color();
$phpColor->setRGB("0070C0");

$objRichText = new PHPExcel_RichText();
$run1 = $objRichText->createTextRun('Main Part of the Title, ');
$run1->getFont()->applyFromArray(array( "bold" => true, "size" => 14, "name" => "Calibri", "color" => array("rgb" => "0070C0")));

$run2 = $objRichText->createTextRun(' and some extra');
$run2->getFont()->applyFromArray(array( "bold" => true, "size" => 10, "name" => "Calibri", "color" => array("rgb" => "0070C0")));

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue("A1", $objRichText);
header ( 'Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet' );
header ( 'Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="sq_test.xlsx"' );
header ( 'Cache-Control: max-age=0' );
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter ( $objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007' );
$objWriter->save ( 'php://output' );
?>
```

Hope this helps someone else along the way.
,

Answer (score 3):

Well you can simplify slightly by using the fluent interface:

```
$objRichText = new PHPExcel_RichText();
$run1 = $objRichText->createTextRun('Main Part of the Title, ');
$run1->getFont()->setBold(true);
$run1->getFont()->setName("Calibri");
$run1->getFont()->setSize("14");
$run1->getFont()->setColor($phpColor);
```

can become

```
$objRichText = new PHPExcel_RichText();
$run1 = $objRichText->createTextRun('Main Part of the Title, ')
    ->getFont()->setBold(true)
        ->setName("Calibri")
        ->setSize("14")
        ->setColor($phpColor);
```

Your attempt to apply from array is likely failing because your array included a top-level reference to the `font`, and you're trying to set it against the font... try setting it just for the attributes that can be applied to fonts:

```
$run2->getFont()
    ->applyFromArray(array( "bold" => true, "size" => 10, "name" => "Calibri", "color" => $phpColor)
);
```

I've never tried that directly myself, so no guarantees

Comment: That got me 90% of the way.  Everything except the color (which as written didn't work ... invalid style array passed) ... which I'll see if I can figure out how to do that part.  Thanks for the response Mark.

Comment: So my color error was passing the color as a PHPExcel_Style_Color.  When I switched it to color => array("rgb" => "0070C0") it worked.  Thanks.